# Number of integral values of $\lambda$

Tags: arithmetic

[image]

From$\lambda cosx> -2$

how they have derived the value of $\lambda$

Comment: I'm seeing some kind of Indian writing that I don't understand. This question has been nominated to be closed, and the Indian writing does not help.

Comment: @RobertSoupe It has both language Hindi and english . and both means the same .

Comment: I would advise you in the future to not include Hindi in your questions (or answers) unless it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $x \in \mathbb R$, we have
$$- 1\leq \cos x \leq 1$$
so if $\lambda \geq 0$ one has
$$ - \lambda \leq \lambda\cos x \leq \lambda$$
So if one wants $ \lambda\cos x >-2$ one must have $-\lambda \geq -2$ that is to say $\lambda \leq 2$. Since $\lambda$ is an integer $\lambda = 0,1,2$.

Now if $\lambda < 0$ one has
$$ - \lambda \geq \lambda\cos x \geq \lambda$$
so $\lambda \geq -2$ that implies $\lambda = -1,-2$ (using the same argument).